# Not able to download the existing function code JSON file via resource group "Automation Script" to use in the ARM deployment

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-resource-group

I have a requirement to deploy the azure resource group implemented at DEV to UAT/PROD.
I have found that after downloading the template.json of the resource group by using the "Automation Script", we cannot see the code of the function available in the resource group.
So, is there any other way to download the Resource group ARM template with the function code?

I need the function code to the same ARM template JSON file to resolve the dependency of the function code into the used LOGIC apps available in the same resource group.
Can anyone share the proper ARM deployment procedure steps which contain the Function APPS, Function CODE, Logic APPS (dependent on the function code), Storage Account etc...?

Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: you wont get the code from the ARM template bu you can specify the path to the code you want to use in ARM: I mean the location of your package. How did you deploy your code to dev ? did you use visual studio ? or you coded from the portal ?

Comment: Hello Thomas, thanks for the response, I have used both the ways, visual studio as well the code in the portal. Also, can you help me to resolve the dependency issue as I specified in my question?

Comment: There is a nice video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2xzjRSOuSKU, should be a good start @MunavvarHusein

Comment: @MunavvarHusein, somehow you package your application in a zip file, upload to blob storage then reference the zip url in your ARM template.

Comment: @Curios Thanks for the video. This video is basically "to deploy the function code into the Azure", but my requirement is, I need to deploy the FUNCTION DLLs from the Visual Studio. And also I need to resolve the dependency issue as well.

Comment: @Thomas I think this will also deploy the function code only by adding the reference of the ZIP.

Comment: @MunavvarHusein what do you mean by this ?

Comment: @Thomas "this" means "somehow you package your application in a zip file, upload to blob storage then reference the zip url in your ARM template."